# Java game error

Tags: java, exception

I'm programming a java game. It's almost done but it's giving me a error (and I don't understand why it happens, the code seems okay).
Error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: projetofinal.ProjetoFinalv2.movimento
    at projetofinal.ProjetoFinalv2.main(ProjetoFinalv2.java:26)
C:\Users\Francisco\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 2 seconds)
```

Here's the code:

```
package projetofinal;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class ProjetoFinalv2 {

    static char[][] tabuleiro;
    static int x, y, jogadorX, jogadorY, pontos;
    static char direction;
    static boolean inGame = true;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        x = 5;
        y = 5;
        tabuleiro = new char[x][y];
        jogadorX = 0;
        jogadorY = 4;
        pontos = 7;
        quadro();
        while(inGame == true)
        {
        customcreator();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String resposta = scan.nextLine();
        movimento(resposta.charAt(0));
        }
    }

      public static void placePot()
    {
        boolean notDone = true;
        while(notDone)
        {
        int tabX = random(0, 4);
        int tabY = random(0, 4);
        if(tabuleiro[tabX][tabY] == '.')
        {
            tabuleiro[tabX][tabY] = 'P';
            notDone = false;
        }
        }
    }

    public static boolean bomba(int x, int y)
    {
        if(tabuleiro[x][y] == 'B')
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static boolean win()  
    {
        if(tabuleiro[jogadorX][jogadorY] == 'F')   
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static boolean gameover()
    {
        if(pontos > 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public static int potepoints(int x, int y)
    {
        if(tabuleiro[x][y] == 'P')
        {
            return random(3,5);
        }
        else
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }

      public static void quadro()
    {
        for(int linha = 0; linha < x; linha++)
        {
            for(int vertical = 0; vertical < y; vertical++)
        {
            tabuleiro[linha][vertical] = '.';
        }
        }

        //Por as bombas na posição correta 

        for(int i = quantos(); i>0; i--)
        {
            boolean tab = true;
            while(tab)
            {
            int tabX = random(1, 3);
            int tabY = random(1, 2);
            if(tabuleiro[tabX][tabY] != 'B')
            {
                tabuleiro[tabX][tabY] = 'B';
                tab = false;
            }
            }
        }
        //Mete o pote que da pontos
        placePot();
    }
    public static void tabuleirocreator()
    { 
        playercreator();
        for(int linha = 0; linha < y; linha++)
        {
            for(int vertical = 0; vertical < x; vertical++)
        {
            System.out.print(tabuleiro[vertical][linha]);
        }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }

    public static void playercreator()
    {

        tabuleiro[jogadorX][jogadorY] = 'J';

    }

    public static void customcreator()
    {
     tabuleiro[0][4] = 'I';
     tabuleiro[4][0] = 'F';
     tabuleirocreator();
    }

    public static int random(int min, int max) 
    {
     Random generator = new Random();
     int Num = generator.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
     return Num;
    }

    public static int quantos()
    {
        return random(2, 3);
    }
}


    //Ciclo do jogo
    public static void movimento(char newDirection)
    {
        if(newDirection == 'w' || newDirection == 'W')
        {
            if(jogadorY > 0)
            {
                tabuleiro[jogadorX][jogadorY] = '.';
            jogadorY -= 1;
            pontos--;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(newDirection == 'a' || newDirection == 'A')
            {
                if(jogadorX > 0)
                {
                tabuleiro[jogadorX][jogadorY] = '.';
                jogadorX -= 1;
                pontos--;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if(newDirection == 's' || newDirection == 'S')
                {
                    if(jogadorY < 4)
                    {
                        tabuleiro[jogadorX][jogadorY] = '.';
                    jogadorY += 1;
                    pontos--;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if(newDirection == 'd' || newDirection == 'D')
                    {
                        if(jogadorX < 4)
                        {
                        tabuleiro[jogadorX][jogadorY] = '.';
                        jogadorX += 1;
                        pontos--;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("Wrong direction!");
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if(bomba(jogadorX, jogadorY))
        {
            pontos = 0;
        }
        int tab = potepoints(jogadorX, jogadorY);
        if(tab != -1)
        {
            pontos += tab;

        }
        if(win())  
        {
            System.out.println("You won");
            inGame = false;
        }
        if(gameover())
        {
            System.out.println("Game Over");
            inGame = false;
        }


    }







    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

I'm a quite noob in java (i started to learn recently) so, i'm sorry if the question is bad.

Comment: You  try to use class compiled with errors. Analyse messages during compilation

Comment: You're making a **new** Scanner with each iteration of the while loop -- Why? Don't do that as that's unnecessary and even potentially dangerous.  And yeah, never try to run code that won't compile. Read the compiler's error messages and fix that first. The messages are usually quite understandable.

Comment: @LewBloch: yes, it **does** make a difference. Usually the compiler's error message is **lot** easier to understand than the JVM's. Yes, we can give him a solution of this above problem, but if we can get him to get in the habit of first looking critically at the compiler message, then we will have helped not just this current problem but also his future problems.  He should at least post the compiler's error message with his question, and then we'll have a better chance of helping him understand it better.

Comment: He did post the compiler's error message with his question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The message tells you that the compiler cannot find a definition for `projetofinal.ProjetoFinalv2.movimento`, a symbol on line 26: `movimento(resposta.charAt(0));`. But `movimento` is not defined *inside the class*. The class definition ends with the closing brace (`}`) just before the orphaned method definition for `movimento`. Not only does that make the method definition inaccessible to the caller, it is utterly illegal to define methods or variables outside of a class.

Comment: Move the right brace `}` that appeard between the methods `quantos` and `movimento` down to the end of the file instead. In this way, `movimento()` will appear to be inside the class,

Comment: it's working, thanks you! Btw, thanks for the patience and for your time, i'm still learning so i make a lot of mistakes.